# Calculate max length of QLineEdit to suit its width

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I created some `QLineEdit`, which have different sizes.

I want to set the max length of those to suit the width of them.

**To be more specific:** for example, with a width of 50, I will only allow to enter about 7 characters, because the size of each character is different.

**How can I exactly calculate the maximum length needed?**

Comment: Can you be more clear: do you want the width needed for seven characters, or how many characters can fit into 50px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a limit based on the width of `myLineEdit` such that it will be able to fit all characters up to that limit by doing this:

```
#include <QFontMetrics>
#include <QLineEdit>

QLineEdit myLineEdit;

// get max character width of the line edit's font
int maxWidth = QFontMetrics(myLineEdit->font()).maxWidth();

// find the character limit based on the max width
int charlimit = myLineEdit.width() / maxWidth;

// set the character limit on the line edit
myLineEdit->setMaxLength(charlimit);
```

However, here are some reasons you probably don't want to in production code:

1. *Stylesheets* - what happenes when your designer gives the edit a 14px border?
2. *Resizing* - you'll have to adjust this on every resize, and I've found that in practice it's a very difficult thing to keep track of. It's not a useful feature if it breaks whenever the GUI gets resized.
3. *Content* - the width of the line edit, especially one that a user can enter text into, is not logically related to the length of text the user may need to enter. This could become an *arbitrary constraint* that frustrates your users. No one *likes* horizontal scrolling, but sometimes there are use cases.

Comment: I understood that maxWidth() will return the width of the widest character in the font, but why the return value was so high up to 32. I did not set font or any style sheet for QLineEdit.

Comment: @user2652023 not sure. There's also an 'averageCharWidth' member that may give you better results.

Comment: 'averageCharWidth' worked better and just like you said it has some limitations, but i can accept it. Thanks for all your supports Nicolas.

Comment: @user2652023 no problem

Answer (score 2):

Use a `QFontMetrics`:

```
QFontMetrics fm(QApplication::font());  // You can use any font here.

int stringWidth = fm.width("Some string");
```

**EDIT:**

At first you have to know when your `QLineEdit` is resized. So you can either derive your own class and reimplement the `resizeEvent()` method, or you can use an *event filter*.

Then create a special validator:

```
class CLengthValidator : public  QValidator
{
public:
    CLenghtValidator(QObject* parent, const QFont & font) 
        :    QValidator(parent), m_maxw(0), m_fm(font)
    {}

    void setMaxValidWidth(int width)
    {
        m_maxw = width;
    }

    State validate(QString & input, int & pos) const override
    {
        int stringWidth = m_fm.width(input);
        if (stringWidth <= m_maxw)
            return Acceptable;
        else
            return Invalid;
    }

private:
    int m_maxw;
    QFontMetrics m_fm;
}
```

Set the validator to your line edit (using the `QLineEdit::setValidator()` method):

```
lineEdit->setValidator(new CLengthValidator(lineEdit, lineEdit->font()));
```

Now, every time the line edit is resized, you have to call `CLengthValidator::setMaxValidWidth()` method with the current line edit width as a parameter. You will do that in your reimplemented `QLineEdit::resizeEvent()` method or in your event filter.

This way you will get a line edit accepting only string which width is not greater than width of actual line edit.

Comment: The OP wants the to calculate the # of letters from a widget width, not the other way around.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I have misunderstood the question quite a bit. I will delete the answer.

Comment: actually, after the OPs edit I'm not sure that this isn't what he's trying to do.

Comment: Let's wait what the OP will say.

Comment: Sorry guys, because when you two answered my question, i am on my weekend. Nicolas understood my question clearly. Thanks for your support Tomas.